# What are the risks of adding third-party Root CA certificate into NTAuth Store?

Tags: certificate-authority, risk, third-party, windows-server

What are the risks associated with importing a third-party Root CA certificate into the Enterprise `NTAuth` Store in a Windows Active Directory domain?
(Except that the CA is then trusted to issue certificates?)

Comment: This is a cross-post of http://serverfault.com/questions/714172/what-are-the-risks-of-adding-third-party-root-ca-certificate-into-ntauth-store/714206#714206